# Replying to a forwarded message

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

D forwards a message he sent to E to me, and I click "reply" and send emails.

My sent emails say that the recipient is D.

Will E see my emails?

Answer (score 2):

No, unless someone shows E your email. You can't always be sure of who else is receiving the same email you are (due to the use of *BCC:*) but you can be sure of who your email will reach -- barring any malicious software.